# AngularJS - mark input field as invalid based on server-side response

Tags: angularjs, validation

Using AngularJS for a form - client side validation is no problem, but I'm trying to figure out how to mark an input field as invalid based on the response from the server (e.g. the input text fails a profanity checker). I've tried using $setValidity to no avail.

Comment: tried using what code and process? Angular 1.3 now has support for remote validation

Comment: It is important to know what version of angular you are trying to implement this on. As charlietfl mentioned, 1.3 has added support for this. 1.2 will require a work-around.